# Are the binaries in Windows Subsystem for Linux the same as when booting a physical Linux PC?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

If we have Windows 10 or 11 and use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with a distribution such as Ubuntu, would we be using the same binaries as if we created a bootable Linux PC?

For instance, when we are using the WSL Bash or Zsh command prompt, if we install:

- Ruby, gcc, and cc
- GPU drivers
- Any Crypto mining executable such as xmrig, t-rex

Does it use the same binaries as it would if we created a bootable Linux drive or USB drive and booted up from there?

Actually, Ruby/gcc/cc might not be a problem, but for Linux GPU drivers, won't that conflict with Windows native GPU drivers?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... using windows is like using linux, not like booting linux

Comment: @jsotola the question is "does WSL provide the same type of environment as a baremetal boot of linux?", specifically asking if the linux version of GPU drivers would be used when running GPU-based software

Answer (score 5):

Well, yes and no (since you ask about several different types of binaries).

##### Application binaries

Yes, assuming you are using an x64 Linux system, the binaries are identical between the two systems.  You can actually take a drive directly out of a physical Linux machine and either:

- Create a tarball of the system which can then be imported into WSL
- Or just `chroot` into the filesystem on that drive (and this [has been done](https://askubuntu.com/q/1376250/1165986)).

There is no "conversion" or change made to the binaries in either of these tasks.

##### Bootstrap binaries

Note that, when *booting* WSL2 this way, you are running *most* of the binaries from the original distribution.  However, the actual kernel and `init` are provided by WSL2, so that it can bootstrap the Windows integration (e.g. ability to run Windows `.exe`'s, networking integration, and [more](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328686/1165986)).

Notably, Systemd does not automatically start.  There are [workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) for Systemd support under WSL2, but it needs to run post-bootstrap, so that WSL's `init` can do it's thing first.

##### Binary Drivers

On the other hand, no, (most) binary *drivers* that expect direct access to *physical hardware* will typically not work unless there is a virtual equivalent provided by WSL.  WSL2 is running in a virtualized environment. There are a few exceptions, though ...

##### USB Device Drivers

It is possible, though, to get direct hardware access to USB devices in Windows by sharing them through USB/IP (from Windows) and connecting to them in WSL/Linux.  For these devices, binary drivers will work.

The most recent WSL2 kernel release has USB/IP support included, but even prior to that, it was possible to build your own kernel with that feature enabled.

##### GPU Compute

Recent WSL2 releases (Windows 11 and Windows 10 21H2) provide the ability to use the *Windows* GPU driver for [WSL2 GPU Compute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gpu-compute) tasks.  This allows Linux binaries which take advantage of GPU compute architecture (e.g. TensorFlow) to leverage the Windows GPU.

I can't speak to crypto-mining (and I doubt Microsoft's going to be pushing that), but I'd expect that it's now possible to use this architecture with those binaries as well.

Answer (score 0):

No. WSL is only Microsoft's interpretation of Linux, and doesn't have the same hardware access as a standalone Linux.

Comment: WSL2 is based on an actual Linux kernel running in a virtual machine. There's no "interpretation". Just like any virtual machine, the hardware drivers may be different but that really depends on how the VM Hypervisor emulates the hardware.